# Is there a better way to write this sub query as it seems to big?

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to retrieve count of the records that are depened on different conditions.I got my expected output but It seems big to me.

```
select count(b.verificationdtl_gid) as received,
(
select count(b.verificationdtl_gid) 
from avs_trn_tverification a
inner join avs_trn_tverificationdtl b on a.verification_gid =b.verification_gid
inner join ver_mst_tverifier c on a.verifier_gid = c.verifier_gid
where c.verifier_gid='VFI1601203046' and b.sap_flag<>'Y'
)as Normal,
(
select count(b.verificationdtl_gid)
from avs_trn_tverification a
inner join avs_trn_tverificationdtl b on a.verification_gid =b.verification_gid
inner join ver_mst_tverifier c on a.verifier_gid = c.verifier_gid
where c.verifier_gid='VFI1601203046' and b.verification_status='Reject'
) as reject,
(
select count(b.verificationdtl_gid) 
from avs_trn_tverification a
inner join avs_trn_tverificationdtl b on a.verification_gid =b.verification_gid
inner join ver_mst_tverifier c on a.verifier_gid = c.verifier_gid
where c.verifier_gid='VFI1601203046' and b.verification_status='Decline'
)as decline
from avs_trn_tverification a
inner join avs_trn_tverificationdtl b on a.verification_gid =b.verification_gid
inner join ver_mst_tverifier c on a.verifier_gid = c.verifier_gid
where c.verifier_gid='VFI1601203046'
```

if the query executes it produces the following result

```
  received    Normal      reject      decline
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
33          24          0           2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select
    count(b.verificationdtl_gid) as received,
    count(case when b.sap_flag <> 'Y' THEN b.verificationdtl_gid end) as Normal,
    count(case when b.verification_status ='Reject' THEN b.verificationdtl_gid end) as reject,
    count(case when b.verification_status ='Decline' THEN b.verificationdtl_gid end) as reject
from avs_trn_tverification a
inner join avs_trn_tverificationdtl b 
    on a.verification_gid = b.verification_gid
inner join ver_mst_tverifier c 
    on a.verifier_gid = c.verifier_gid
where
    c.verifier_gid = 'VFI1601203046'
```